# Пропадает часть изображения при увеличении масштаба OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

Пропадает часть изображения при увеличении масштаба OpenGL. Как увеличить глубину?

Инициализация:

```
void Widget::initializeGL()
{
    qglClearColor(Qt::white);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_FILL);
}

void Widget::resizeGL(int nWidth, int nHeight)
{
    glViewport(0, 0,nWidth,nHeight);//,1900,1200);// nHeight, nHeight);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}


void Widget::paintGL()
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();                                                                          
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glScalef(scale, scale, scale);
    glTranslatef(xL, yL, zL);
    glRotatef(xRotation, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glRotatef(yRotation, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glRotatef(zRotation, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

[image: a busy cat]
[image: a busy cat]

Comment: Это задняя плоскость отсечения (zFar clipping plane). Так как вы никак не настраиваете матрицу проекции, она у вас в дефолтном состоянии, и, скорее всего, режет по 1 .. -1.

Comment: добавил gluPerspective(60.0f,(GLfloat)1000/(GLfloat)1000,1.0f,100000.0f);

Comment: нет изменений1.

Comment: Добавьте это в текст вопроса (обновите код и картинки), а не в комментарии! =)

Comment: А что за объект вы рисуете? Это куб? Или точнее пол губа? Или это просто текстура такая?

Comment: Что-то типо системы координат.